# Why is there a white edge when cropping an image with UIGraphicsContext?

Tags: ios, swift, uigraphicscontext

I am cropping an image with:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(croppingRect.size)
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

context?.clip(to: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rect.width, height: rect.height))        
image.draw(at: CGPoint(x: -rect.origin.x, y: -rect.origin.y))

let croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

The cropped image sometimes has a 1px white edge on the right and bottom border. The right bottom corner zoomed in to see the individual pixels looks like this. Apparently the border is not plain white but shades of white which may come from later compression.

[image]

Where does this white edge artifact come from?

Comment: I have tried your code and working fine for me , Could you pls show your rect and  croppingRect

Comment: Thanks, found the issue, see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was that the values of the `croppingRect` were not full pixels.

As the values for `x`, `y`, `width`, `height` where calculated `CGFloat` numbers the results would sometimes be fractional numbers (e.g. `1.3` instead of `1.0`). The solution was to round these values:

```
let cropRect = CGRect(
   x: x.rounded(.towardZero), 
   y: y.rounded(.towardZero),
   width: width.rounded(.towardZero),
   height: height.rounded(.towardZero))
```

The rounding has to be `.towardZero` (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpointroundingrule) what it means) because the cropping rectangle should (usually) not be larger than the image rect.

Comment: Well !! That's valuable tip